# Django installing multiple apps on the same page

Tags: python, django, url

I'm very new to Django and definitely not very experienced.

Anyhow, I've startet my own site on the local network and succesfully created an app using Django 1.4. But when I tried to start another app, it only seems to show up on my website under some (in my eyes) specieal circumstances.

Whenever my urls.py file looks like this:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', 'myapp1.views.home1', name='home1'),
        url(r'^$', 'myapp2.views.home2', name='home2'),
```

The first app is shown on the page, but when I switch them around the second app is shown on the page:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', 'myapp2.views.home2', name='home2'),
        url(r'^$', 'myapp1.views.home1', name='home1'),
```

as I said, I'm no very experience, so if you need me to provide more information let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django works by matching a URL pattern to some code that you have written in `views.py`.

In your case, you are pointing the same pattern (`^$`) to two view methods.  Django will stop when it finds a match, so when you switch the patterns around, it will always match the first entry in the list.

If you change your patterns to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^/two$', 'myapp2.views.home2', name='home2'),
        url(r'^$', 'myapp1.views.home1', name='home1'),
```

Now when you type `http://localhost:8000/two` `home2` will be executed, and when you type `http://localhost:8000/` `home1` will be executed.

Comment: So if I want two apps to be shown at the same time, I need to only have 1 views.py file?

Comment: You have 1 views file per application you create, and you have one `urls.py` that maps URL patterns to the methods you have defined in the `views.py` of multiple apps.

In django, one "file" can do multiple things; there is no such mapping of one app = one file. The applications you create in django define multiple views (in one `views.py` file), and then you have to map urls to these view functions - and you do that from `urls.py`

Comment: Do you know of any article describing this subject in detail? Although you seem to explain it quite well

Comment: I suggest you read through the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/), and then post specific questions; but do a [search](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#searching) first and you might find that your question was already asked and answered.